# Ring buffer implementation linker error

Tags: c++, linker, buffer, abstract-data-type

I am implementing a Ring Buffer construct in C++ in the course of a workshop we are going through.
Now, the source code may be okay, but the linker just won't work properly - or more likely my code or project settings.

**Header:**
http://pastie.org/private/rbx84gvlzc9ipzk1mzczg

**Source:**
http://pastie.org/private/kkjjhwywfljgnw75jlmxsq

**The build process says:**

> 1>------ Build started: Project: RingBuffer, Configuration: Debug
>   Win32 ------ 1>  RingBuffer.cpp 1>RingBuffer.obj : error LNK2019:
>   unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall
>   RingBuffer::RingBuffer(int)" (??0RingBuffer@@QAE@H@Z) referenced in
>   function _main 1>C:\Users*.*\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\RingBuffer\Debug\RingBuffer.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1
>   unresolved externals
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Thanks in advice for any helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not *defined* the constructor

```
RingBuffer(int storageAmount);
```

You gave definition of

```
RingBuffer();
```

But using the previous one in `main`.

This is clear from the error message

```
unresolved external symbol public: __thiscall RingBuffer::RingBuffer(int)
```

Linker can not find the method to link.